# Transpose emacs rectangles

Tags: emacs, text-editing

Suppose I have this text:

```
RUN_
RUN_
RUN_
RUN_
RUN_
```

and want this one:

```
RUN_A
RUN_B
RUN_C
RUN_D
RUN_E
```

I would like to be able to write `ABCDE` and somehow `transpose' it
and kill-yank it as a rectangle.

Can this be done without too much lisp hacking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun insert-column (chars)
  (interactive "sChars to enter: ")
  (insert-rectangle (mapcar 'string (string-to-list chars))))
```

Comment: This is good, tanks.
It would be even better if one could do it for several lines together (like rectangles).

Comment: You mean more than just one character per line?  That's just a matter of splitting the input string differently.  (But then you might as well just got with the plain rectangle operations...)

Comment: I mean being able to kill a region in a special way and yank it in columns. But the code you provided is already pretty useful.

Comment: Well, for that you have the usual rectangle commands -- in this case, `C-x r k` to kill a rectangular region, and `C-x r y` to paste it elsewhere.

Comment: I meant something similar to this usual command but with *transposition*.

Answer (score 0):

Mark relevant text. Then press:

M-x delete-trailing-whitespace

Place cursor at beginning. Type the following (with returns at the relevant places)

M-x map-query-replace-regexp

$

A B C D E

This procedure cleans first the trailing whitespace per line, then, per line end inserts A, B, etc. one by one at these end of lines. Other replacement patterns, are, of course, possible. It is not strictly a rectangle transpose, but quite versatile and is typically closer to what one wishes, as replacements are not necessarily in the same column, but rather determined by pattern.